# Access DOM embedded PDF in Chrome

Tags: vba, selenium, pdf, dom, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to access the DOM of a embedded PDF file opened in Chrome?
If you simply open the DevTools in Chrome, only the EMBED tag is visible:

[image]

But there is a mouse over PDF file opened in Chrome and right-click => code view, then a completely different page code opens:
[image]

Can I get access to it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so it looks like you've got multiple documents on a page. Its similar to iFrames in web design. I'm not sure 100% because I cant look through the link.

But I'd highly recommend downloading the PDF as a file, then using ADOBE Pro's library to scrape or w/e with the PDF functions. You eliminate the whole aspect of timing, page loads, and page changes, when you get a direct link to a pdf, and then manipulate the data on the user or cloud PC.

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, I agree with you, but in my situation this method is not suitable.
The fact is that the link to the PDF file in the example is taken as an example and is not the link with which I work.
In my case, it happens like this: on the site, I click the button to create a file, after which the PDF file is generated and opens embedded in the Chrome window. The file link is always the same although a new PDF file is generated each time. It’s not possible to catch the link.
I get an embedded PDF document in Chrome with a link like this: www.somesite.domain/file

Comment: I tried to save the file using the examples that you prompted me in another topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038325/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-from-browser-using-excel-vba) but in the end an empty PDF file is downloaded. Apparently, because the file on the page without a direct link

Comment: well there is probably a direct link, you just need to open the page with Chrome DevTools recording the network traffic. You can find that on the F12 in Chrome and on the network tab in the new window that pops up. Eventually you're going to see a Request in the list of Requests that is the PDF link ((and you can hit CTRL + F when you've clicked on the network tab, to search for text if there's a lot of requests and narrow it down)) Basically, there's gonna be a 'link' or headers or query string or cookie that specifies how the web page fetches that pdf from the server, try and find that & lmk